# Correct memory management pattern for alloc/initing a view, adding to subview and returning

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management

Im sure this sort of question has been asked to death and I understand what I *should* be doing, but its not working. My app is crashing:

Here's the code:

```
    PDFViewController *cv = [[PDFViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PDFViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
cv.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 748);

    [self.view addSubview:cv.view];
```

Now, if I send a release message to the cv instance:

```
      [cv release];
```

My application crashes. Same if I add it to the autorelease pool (on alloc/init).
Now my concern is this:

0) I'm alloc/init'ing, so its my duty to release (or add to auto-release pool).

1) Calling addSubview:cv.view increments the retain count of the cv.

2) I should be able to send it a release message, because it's being retained by the 
self.view.

3) What's wrong?

TIA.

*EDIT*
**Solution**

```
PDFViewController *cv = [[PDFViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PDFViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self presentModalViewController:cv animated:YES];
```

Comment: What's the message you get when it crashes?

Comment: I just get an ERROR_BAD_EXEC or similar high level message. Though I can cause it to happen by adding a [cv release]; definitely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling addSubview:cv.view **does not** increments the retain count of the cv object.  It does increments the retained count on "cv.view" therefore "self.view" only retains "cv.view".

Comment: Ah you're right. So, how do I make this work? What I mean is that I alloc'd/init'd the object ...

Comment: The solution is to not use `UIViewControllers` like this. They are made to either display full-screen or be embedded within another view controller (nav controller, tabbar, split view, etc). It looks like you want this view to be full screen. Try using `[self presentModalViewController:cv animated:YES];`

Comment: Right on. Did this instead     

    PDFViewController *cv = [[PDFViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PDFViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self presentModalViewController:cv animated:YES];

Answer (score 1):

`cv.view` is a getter that automatically has the view ivar calling autorelease. Your best bet is probably to create an ivar `_cv` and use that instead of a local variable. Then safely release the ivar in your dealloc: `[_cv release]; _cv = nil;`